# Read lookup value dynamically from list and fill select box

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have one list with different musical **Genres**, this list is linked as a lookup to the lists **Bands** and **Records**. When I register a new band I set the typical genres played by this band and when registering a new record I register band and genres.

Is there any recommended technique to automatically (and dynamically) read the genres from the Band item and fill the genres list when creating a new record?

I was thinking to create some integration web service that can read genres from bands returning a json and fill the genres list with the help of a javascript. I have the "onchange" functionality in place.

**New Band**

[image: New Band]

**New record**

[image: New record]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the SPServices javascript library - it has very good and easy to use support for providing this sort of dynamic interaction with built in SharePoint edit pages. http://spservices.codeplex.com/

Comment: +1 to be more specific, look at the SPCascadeDropdowns method http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=$().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns&referringTitle=Documentation The Web service you're talking about is built in SharePoint and that's what SPServices uses (it returns xml, not JSON). The only other option I can think of would be to use Infopath.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using a list picker field to bring the Band Name into the Records List, why not bring the Genres field from the Bands List when you choose the Band Name?

Comment: I think Kwickie is correct on this.. If the Genres are available already when the bands list is populated why not carry it with you? I am not familiar with sharepoint but I think simply creating a band model and adding a list(of genres) would suffice. Then when the band is selected use jquery to update the correct field with the contents of the model.genres list..